# JavaScript. Need to concat two arrays inside the function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, concatenation

I have two arrays of objects. I concat them before the function in one. Also I have function that sorts array by its props. Got some problems with visibility.

What i need to do?

I need to put my two arrays inside the function and concat them inside and in the end i want to have a function with such structure:

function sortBy(arr1, arr2, key) {
...
}

Need to console.log my function just by putting in it needed prop.

Appreciate ur help.

```
const listObjects = [
    {name: 'Kolya', age: 34},
    {name: 'Valya', age: 1},
    {name: 'Nesver', age: 24},
    {name: 'Valera', age: 61},
    {name: 'Ira', age: 15}
];

const people = [
    {name: 'Andrey', age: 26, budget: 101000},
    {name: 'Masha', age: 25, budget: 80000},
    {name: 'Dima', age: 18, budget: 90000},
    {name: 'Egor', age: 45, budget: 151000},
    {name: 'Sveta', age: 14, budget: 70000},
    {name: 'Stas', age: 21, budget: 30000},
    {name: 'Dasha', age: 17, budget: 15000}
];


const x = listObjects.concat(people);

function sortBy(key) {

    let sortOrder = 1;
    if(key[0] === "-") {
        sortOrder = -1;
        key = key.substr(1);
    }
    return function (a,b) {
        let result = (a[key] < b[key]) ? -1 : (a[key] > b[key]) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}

console.log(x.sort(sortBy('name')));
```

Comment: Are you looking for this: `(a, b, key) => a.concat(b).sort(by(key))`?

Comment: @georg could u please explain me how can i use it in my function?

Comment: That snippet answers your request: "I need to put my two arrays inside the function and concat them inside and in the end i want to have a function with such structure: function sortBy(arr1, arr2, key) { ... }"

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question, your code seems to be working fine. Can you try to rephrase it. "Problems with visibility". Not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

```
  { name: "Kolya", age: 34 },
  { name: "Valya", age: 1 },
  { name: "Nesver", age: 24 },
  { name: "Valera", age: 61 },
  { name: "Ira", age: 15 }
];

const people = [
  { name: "Andrey", age: 26, budget: 101000 },
  { name: "Masha", age: 25, budget: 80000 },
  { name: "Dima", age: 18, budget: 90000 },
  { name: "Egor", age: 45, budget: 151000 },
  { name: "Sveta", age: 14, budget: 70000 },
  { name: "Stas", age: 21, budget: 30000 },
  { name: "Dasha", age: 17, budget: 15000 }
];

const x = listObjects.concat(people);



console.log(
  x.sort(function(a, b) {
    var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
    var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
    if (x < y) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (x > y) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  })
);
```

You can do this like that.